# oderid sort not work correclty in number more than 1000 in commerce_orders views

Tags: views

I look at the `commerce_orders` views, and I see some strange there, when I set sort record according by orderID it not work correctly for number more than 1000 ,it seems that only 3 first digit consider in sort, Is this a bug in views? 
appreciate any help

[image]

and query is :

```
SELECT commerce_order.order_number AS commerce_order_order_number, commerce_order.order_id AS order_id, commerce_order.uid AS commerce_order_uid, commerce_order.created AS commerce_order_created, commerce_customer_profile_field_data_commerce_customer_billing.profile_id AS commerce_customer_profile_field_data_commerce_customer_billi, users_commerce_order.name AS users_commerce_order_name, users_commerce_order.uid AS users_commerce_order_uid, commerce_order.status AS commerce_order_status, 'commerce_customer_profile' AS field_data_commerce_customer_address_commerce_customer_profi, 'commerce_order' AS field_data_commerce_order_total_commerce_order_entity_type
FROM 
{commerce_order} commerce_order
LEFT JOIN {users} users_commerce_order ON commerce_order.uid = users_commerce_order.uid
LEFT JOIN {field_data_commerce_customer_billing} field_data_commerce_customer_billing ON commerce_order.order_id = field_data_commerce_customer_billing.entity_id AND (field_data_commerce_customer_billing.entity_type = 'commerce_order' AND field_data_commerce_customer_billing.deleted = '0')
LEFT JOIN {commerce_customer_profile} commerce_customer_profile_field_data_commerce_customer_billing ON field_data_commerce_customer_billing.commerce_customer_billing_profile_id = commerce_customer_profile_field_data_commerce_customer_billing.profile_id
WHERE (( (commerce_order.status NOT IN  ('cart', 'checkout_checkout', 'checkout_shipping', 'checkout_review', 'checkout_payment', 'checkout_complete')) ))
ORDER BY commerce_order_order_number DESC
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: It looks like they are ordered as text instead of ints. Can you show us the SQL of your query and structure of the table that contains ids?

Comment: @Mołot This field is order_number

Comment: @Mołot , question updated and query comes in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in [`commerce_order_schema`](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!order!commerce_order.install/function/commerce_order_schema/DC), order number is not a number, it's a string:

```
'order_number' => array(
    'description' => 'The order number displayed to the customer.', 
    'type' => 'varchar', 
    'length' => 255, 
    'not null' => FALSE,
  ),
```

This means that your view **works as designed**, sorting this text field that accidentally contains numbers alphabetically. Which, again accidentally, gave you *illusion* of numeric sort when numbers was in [100-999] range.

If you need something that's guaranteed to be numeric and ordered the way orders was placed, use either `order_id` (`'type' => 'serial'`) or `created` (`'type' => 'int'`).

Comment: tnx for you antention. can you tell me exactly what I should do?

Comment: @zhilevan I thought I did, in my last paragraph. Simply sort by something int-sortable.

Comment: ,please tell me exactly where I do it, in view, in field managment?

Comment: @zhilevan in Views, look for Sort criteria on the bottom right of your view settings ( example.com/admin/structure/views/view/your_view_name )

Comment: thank you very much, yes , I use order_id instead order_number and in table_sort set sort as order_id and work correctly :).